flutter >= 3.16 gradle migration with version catalogue
I want to use AGP 8.x, Gradle 8.x and flutter >= 3.16 with version catelogue.
I followed this instruction https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply.
But the following build-error happens.
class org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated cannot be cast to class org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings ...

class org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated cannot be cast to class org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings ...

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

I tried it with the following code:

AGP: 8.4
Gradle 8.6
Flutter: 3.22.2


{app_root}/android/build.gradle

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    alias libs.plugins.android.application apply false
    alias libs.plugins.kotlin.android apply false
}


{app_root}/android/settings.gradle

In gradle, Version catalogue cannot be used in settings.gradle. I guess it's not allowed. So I moved these plugins definitions into build.gradle as usual.
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

/*
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    alias libs.plugins.android.application apply false
    //id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    alias libs.plugins.kotlin.android apply false
    //id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}
 */

include ":app"


{app_root}/android/app/build.gradle

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    alias libs.plugins.android.application
    alias libs.plugins.kotlin.android
}
...


I understand that the Flutter plugin is located in {flutter_sdk}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/. My question is whether the latest Flutter SDK is capable of using the Gradle version catalogue.

You should know that gradually adding new migrations for projects. the contents of the file
android/build.gradle
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
  }

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

content of the settings.grale
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id("dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader") version "1.0.0"
    id("com.android.application") version "7.3.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.3.14" apply false
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") version "2.9.9" apply false
}

include ':app'

content of the app/build.gradle
app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystorePropertiesFile.withInputStream { stream ->
        keystoreProperties.load(stream)
    }
}

android {

    // ----- BEGIN flavorDimensions (autogenerated by flutter_flavorizr) -----
    flavorDimensions += "flavor-type"

    productFlavors {
        development {
            dimension "flavor-type"
            applicationId "your_app_Id"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "your_app_name"
        }
        staging {
            dimension "flavor-type"
            applicationId "your_app_Id"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "your_app_name"
        }
        production {
            dimension "flavor-type"
            applicationId "your_app_Id"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "your_app_name"
        }
    }

    // ----- END flavorDimensions (autogenerated by flutter_flavorizr) -----

    namespace = "your_app_nameSpace"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude "DebugProbesKt.bin"
        exclude "META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your_app_Id"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // Consider removing this line if you rely on automatic signing for debug builds
            // signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.3.0')
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics")
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

I think you need to see the versions of your kotlin, android and gradle so that it is compatible I hope this can help you especially with the new version of Android studio ladybug. Sincerely

Your gradle doesn't use a version catelogue.
